# Need help regarding nodejs restful task

Tags: node.js, rest

My task is a nodejs backend task which contains restful service which contains endpoints for adding and removing bulletins and also use sequlizejs for database.

After reviewing this project, the reviewer says that I do not know restful service and also project is not scalable without giving any details so may I know what is the problem with project.

Project is on github https://github.com/mregydev/testrest

Comment: You should ask what he means. Stack overflow is not the right place to ask "please review my entire codebase and tell me why it's not REST and not scalable."

Comment: it's clearly rest but he probably just means you should follow standards for different types of calls to the same endpoint name. Right now you could replace every get, put, and delete with a post and it would still work just as well because you've changed the endpoint for every function

Comment: Example of call `/getBulletin/:id` should be `/bulletin/:id`. Look at [HTTP Methods](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) to correct your routage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is your route... to do CRUD, you usually use a standard way of routes for your endpoints. for example,

```
To create a bulletin, you use POST /bulletins
To read the bulletin list, you use GET /bulletins
To read a specific bulletin, you use GET /bulletins/:bulletinId
To update a specific bulletin, you use PUT (or PATCH) /bulletins/:bulletinId
To delete a specific bulletin, you use DELETE /bulletins/:bulletinId
```

You may read https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4